# Why is Request.Form empty after SAML 2.0 authentication redirect from IDP?

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0

I'm implementing SAML 2.0 using AspNetSaml library and JumpCloud as IDP in an ASP.NET Web Forms application. Below is my Service Provider metadata that I've configured in JumpCloud:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                     validUntil="2020-04-25T04:40:01Z"
                     cacheDuration="PT604800S"
                     entityID="SPEntityID1234567892">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                     Location="https://localhost:44338/SSOLogin.aspx"
                                     index="1" />

    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

The SAML request is being initiated from Login button on the Default page in my ASP.NET Web Forms application.

```
            var samlEndpoint = "<jumpcloud saml app end point>";

        var request = new AuthRequest(
            "SPEntityID1234567892", //TODO: put your app's "unique ID" here
            "https://localhost:44338/SSOLogin.aspx" //TODO: put Assertion Consumer URL (where the provider should redirect users after authenticating)
            );

        //redirect the user to the SAML provider
        Response.Redirect(request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint));
```

After I initiate the SAML request, I'm redirected to my IDP and it asks for authentication. But after authentication when I'm redirected back to my application (https://localhost:44338/SSOLogin.aspx), the Forms object is empty.

[image]

This makes the Request.Form["SAMLResponse"] object as null.

Can someone please provide some pointers on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!